# Joomla can't send SMTP email on GCE

Tags: joomla, smtp, google-compute-engine, centos7

I have a weird problem.
I have install Centos7 on GCE. 
I know that Google blocked port 25, 465, 587 for SMTP. To make thing simple, I've decided to use Mailgun for MTA.

Mailgun is superbly easy. Everything works fine on localhost. I can send email from Joomla instance.

However, when i I moved to GCE, Joomla (3.5.1) not able to send email. It keeps telling me SMTP connect() failed.

I also tried using another SMTP agent like Gmail, GApps etc. It works on localhost but not GCE.

Is there setting that i missed?

Comment: Did you check this link https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail/using-mailgun . Is everything done as per requirement.

Comment: Seems to be issue with your server config. You can debug smtp error and find out the real problem. Here is a link that may help you https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/issues/9373

Comment: I found out that its my server setting. I've followed your suggestion regarding Google Computer Engine setting.
Now, i've received  "Relaying denied (in reply to RCPT TO command)" error in my log.

Comment: This is probably due to the authentication failure. Just receheck the joomla settings.

Comment: ok. success. i have to use Sendmail for Mailer option in Joomla's Global Gonfiguration.
Thanks Amit Ray for your guide.